# How to Monitoring the lines between an Atmega8 and a LCD using Atmega32

Tags: avr, atmega, lcd, character-lcd

I have a device that it use an Atmega8 to send some data to a 2*8 character LCD. the LCD has 8 pins and the pins are as below from left to right:

**DB7 | DB6 | DB5 | DB4 | En(Clock) | RS | VDD | VFF**

I think it is a *HD44780* with DB0...3 , Contrast and WR connected to GND.

By the way, I want to monitor the lines between this *LCD* and *Atmega8* using an *Atmega32*. I mean I want to achieve the data that transferring between them and send it to my computer's COM port and ....

I checked the [datasheet of HDD44789](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/GDM1602K-Extended.pdf) (A 2*16 LCD) and I found this :

[image]

Although this has 8 bit for data and mine has 4 bit, but I think both have a single procedure to print data on the LCD.

Now I want to know, how I can read the data on the lines using an Atmega32. for example can I connect **En** to  Interrupt-0 pin and in falling edge read **DB4....7**? Does it work?

And another question, when we send data to LCD in 4bit-packs, we send high nibble first or we send low nibble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I connect En to Interrupt-0 pin and in falling edge read DB4....7?

Essentially, yes. You also want to read the RS pin to see if the data is for control or text.

> And another question, when we send data to LCD in 4bit-packs, we send high nibble first or we send low nibble?

Higher nibble first.

Comment: I configure my Interrupt on **rising** edge or **falling** edge on E pin?

Comment: The Falling edge.